# Elegant way to create a List<int> just by (int)from and (int)to

Tags: c#, for-loop, generic-list

I want an elegant way to create a new `List<int>` just by to integers.

Example:

```
var from = 2;
var to = 5;
```

What I want is this:

```
List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Of course I could do it in a simple loop like this:

```
var results = new List<int>();
for (var i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
     results.Add(i);
}
```

But I want some kind of more efficient or elegant way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).ASPX):

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(2, 4).ToList();
```

Note the `4` here refers to the number of integers to include in the result list. So to create a range specified by `from` and `to` variables, use:

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(from,to-from+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

use Enumerable.Range

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1); // +1 to include last number
```